# django1.7 Queryset select distinct data from multiple models

Tags: python-2.7, django-queryset, django-1.7

HIGHLIGHT

I'm trying to retrieve distinct data from multiple models.What is the best solution to achieve this ? I need Django1.7 code .

PROBLEM

I want to retrieve complete details of files' starting with `search_key`,only if the requested user has permission to access it.

RELATED DATA

modes.py

```
class FileDetails(models.Model):
    fileId = models.CharField(max_length = 100,primary_key=True,db_index=True)
    fileName=models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    fileSize=models.IntegerField(max_length = 1000,blank=True,default=0)

class Permission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)


class FileShare(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    file_requested=models.ForeignKey(FileDetails)
    permission=models.ManyToManyField(Permission)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filedetails =FileDetails.objects.filter(fileName__startswith=search_key)
        for f in filedetails:

            fileshare=FileShare.objects.get( file_requested=f.fileId)

            try:
                if fileshare.permission.get(user=current_user):

                    filedet =FileDetails.objects.get(fileId=fileshare.file_requested)
                    ownership.append(fileshare.owner)
                    FileID.append(filedet.fileId)
                    FileName.append(str(filedet.fileName.split('Temp/')[1]))
                    FileSize.append(float(format(filedet.fileSize/1000000.0, '.2f')))

                    filedetails=zip(FileName,FileSize,FileID,ownership)          
            except ObjectDoesNotExist :
                    pass
```